# Points in lines extraction of coordinates automate

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, line, coordinates

I'm currently working on a project with ArcMap.

I'm having a problem on how to extract the x,y info of all the points in a line, meter by meter.
This is the problem & objective:
So I have 1 line, with 50 meters, with x,y information of the 1st vertice and the last one.

How do I extract the coordinates, starting from the 1st vertice, of all the points, meter by meter, of the same line?

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Hi, I'm using ArcMap. I've tried to run 2 tools. First GeneratePointsAlongLine and then Split Line at Point. However I have a lot of Lines, and my ArcMap somehow always crashes. So I was thinking about export the info about the start and end point of Lines and calculate outside the software the divisions by a meter of that Line.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with that additional and relevant information.